# How to get value in email after + sign in php

Tags: php, swiftmailer, gmail-imap

I am reading an inbox from `email@gmail.com` in PHP.

The `to` field, as it is visible in `gmail-ui`, has the format `email+2389udskhjk23@gmail.com`.

I'm fetching headers in two ways:

```
$headers = imap_headerinfo($mbox, $imap_idx);
$raw_headers = imap_fetchheader($mbox, $imap_idx);
```

both only display `email@gmail.com` as being the `to` field. How can I get the full value instead?

Comment: Did you try parsing the mail?

Comment: do you mean the body of the email?